# Where on EC2/ElasticBeanstalk AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID is stored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

To perform some action on Cognito on my dev environment I need to have: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY so I set them as environment variables. On the staging server I didn't set it and app works, so I assume it should be added automatically by EB or EC2 or anything else. Where can I find it and change?

Comment: How did you set env variable ? Update question with that code.

Comment: I think that doesn't matter. On local env I need to defined environment vars and it works. On stag I didn't define them and it's still works. So they should be defined somewhere already

Comment: env variable gets stored at below files on linux system 
.bashrc, .bash_profile

Comment: You should really be using EC2 Instance Profiles instead of access keys when your code is running on an EC2 server. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html

Comment: @MarkB in fact this is an answer. That's true, I don't use access_keys there, but there is IAM policy which allow me all operations. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to store credentials on your instance. Instead use IAM roles.

For Elastic Beanstalk look into Instance Profiles and Service Roles. This link will help you put everything inplace.

> An instance profile is a container for an AWS Identity and Access
>   Management (IAM) role that you can use to pass role information to an
>   EC2 instance when the instance starts. When you launch an environment
>   in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment management console, the
>   console creates a default instance profile, called
>   aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role, and assigns managed policies with
>   default permissions to it.

[Using Elastic Beanstalk with AWS Identity and Access Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.html)